# Android JSON get value

Tags: android, json

This is the JSON I have:

> {"success":"1","message":"Login successful","firstname":"FIRST"}

How do I get the value 1 from success?

I have tried this:

```
    public void startLogin(View v) throws JSONException {


    EditText username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editUsername);
    EditText password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editPassword);

    String usr = username.getText().toString();
    String pw = password.getText().toString();

    String url = "hidden for privacy purposes";

    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);

    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

            try {
                JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
                JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
                boolean success = obj.getBoolean("success");
                if(success) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "LOGIN CORRECT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FAILED LOGIN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }



            } catch(JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "JSON error! " + e, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
    });

    queue.add(jsonObjectRequest);


    }

}
```

This gives me a JSONException:

> org.json.JSONException: Not a primitive array: class
>   org.json.JSONObject

This is my first time using JSON for anything, so I feel like a newbie. I have looked at some other questions posted on here and tried those solutions to no avail. If anyone could point me in the right direction or show me how to do this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Try to query the response object directly. You don't need to transform it. It's coming already transformed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

replace:

```
            JSONArray arr = new JSONArray(response);
            JSONObject obj = arr.getJSONObject(0);
```

with

```
            JSONObject obj =  new JSONObject(response)
```

you do not have an array as input

Comment: The response object itself looks it is a JsonObject. You can query it directly then.

Comment: Thank you. That worked. I also had to change success from a boolean to a string, of course. Will mark accepted once it lets me.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any initial transformation becuase using the JsonObjectRequest you are already obtaining a JsonObject as the response.

This means the object passed in the onResponse callback (response) is itself a **JsonObject**.

That said means you can directly query the object through the JsobObject API.

If success is a String you can do `response.getString("success)` or if it's an Int you do `response.getInt("success")` to retrieve success' data.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering a JSON object, not an array.